# disable tableview with all elements

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I working with swift 4 for macOS and I have a NSButton, which should disable my NSTableView with all elements (textfields, buttons, ...)

In the IBAction of my button I have this code lines:

```
myTableView.deselectAll(nil)
myTableView.isEnabled = false
```

This works good, but I found a little "bug".
If I select a textfield of my tableview (edit mode on)
and press after that my button, the tableview will be disabled and all selected rows will unselect, but I can edit the content of my textfield without a problem, because the "edit mode" is still on.

Must I disable all my textfields in the tableview manually or is there an elegant trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make NSTextField lose responder with

```
view.window?.makeFirstResponder(view.window)
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: little correction: I can edit **all** my textfields of that row, which was selected, before my button will press. with your code, my selected textfield lost the focus. but I can select this and the other textfield of my last selected row and edit them without a problem oO all other rows and textfields are "disabled"

Comment: Are you deselecting all rows and disabling table view?

Comment: `myTableView.deselectAll(nil)
myTableView.isEnabled = false
view.window?.makeFirstResponder(view.window)`

Comment: Does your table view allows empty selection? You can check it on storyboard or via `allowsEmptySelection` property

Comment: at the moment: no

Comment: So set it to true and check again

Comment: than my app crashes after I pressed the button with the error `An uncaught exception was raised; Row -1 out of row range [0-4] for rowViewAtRow:createIfNeeded:` The next thing is, that my user should normally not be allowed to do "empty selections"

Comment: okay, i solve it now with a `myTableView.reloadData()` after the lines and it seems to work :)